# Design a java based menu so that it's easier to add new options

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I am trying to create a java console program which displays a Menu with few options. Each option selection performs some independent operation say executing a script or performing some db operation, for example:

```
1 option1title  
2 option2title  
3 option3title  
...
```

I need to design this such that I should be able to add new options easily. say just by adding a new class.
Some options might show a submenu as well.

**Design thoughts that I have**

Have an interface say `IOption` with methods like `optionTitle`, `optionAction`. So each `Option` in the menu would implement this interface and write its action & title.

*How do I display the menu ?*
I can have a class which where each option is registered. Say a list of all the options. Then my main program would iterate over this classes and shows the menu. Option selection would call the action of that particular class.
Otherwise I can use reflection/annotation to get the all the classes which implement this interface and show the menu ----> This might be an overkill.

Is there any better way to design this ? Any design patterns that I can bring in ? My priority is good design.

With my solution also, if I want to add a new option, I would need to register each option in a list, implement the class etc.
Instead of adding to a list in register class, how about having the link between `optionTitle` and class info in an xml file or something ?

And I'll have submenus as well. Other than writing this in the `itemAction` method, any better way to design this ?

Let me know If I need to add more info.
Note: This will always be invoked from command prompt. Either shell/ windows command prompt. I don't need any GUI for this.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327748/design-a-java-based-menu-so-that-its-easier-to-add-new-options "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Delete the cross post in SO. This is the correct site for this question since it is a design question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proposed design:**

You could use the [command pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html):

- A command interface defines the methods related to a menu option (i.e. command).  The most important method here is `optionAction()` (corresponds to the `execute()` method of the pattern).
- Concrete commands are classes that implement this interface :   `optionAction()` is overridden to define the actions that shall be executed for a specific command.
- When concrete commands are instantiated by a client (your `main()` ?), a reference to a receiver object is stored.  That object will be used to execute the action later.
- A specific concrete command class implements a menu loop as action.  But instead of hard-coding every different submenu in its own class, use a single `SubmenuCommand` class, the instances of which will refer to a menu object that has a list of options (commands).
- The invoker will execute the created commands when needed.  In your case, you could simplify the invoker:  your `main()` would somehow invoke the command corresponding to the toplevel menu.  And this one would invoke the chosen commands.

**Variants of this design:**

The menu objects could be constructed during initialization. Typically, you'd use the [builder pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) to initialize each menu programatically. Then it could make sense to use `optionTitle()`.

However, you could also load the menu from a configuration file. In this case, the `optionTitle()` would be useless: you'd read that title from the configuration file (with flexibility to customize the text, and even possibility to localize/translate the menus).  In principle you'd do that in the the director of the builder, but if you want also to configure other commands, a [factory method pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html) could be considered as well.

If you opt for the dynamically load of menus, there are a couple of delicate points to handle:

- first you need to link you text of menus with command classes.  Either you use reflection to identify the right classes by name, or -- much simpler -- you use a map that links keywords corresponding to commands to class specific factories (the map would be static, and initialized before the config file is parsed).
- dependencies between menus:  the simplest way would be to organize your menus in bottom up order, so to be sure that a menu is always loaded/created before it is referred to in other menus. Similarly to command classes, you'd also have a map of menus (the map would be dynamic, and populated as new menus are loaded : the menu structure could hence be totally dynamic and reconfigurable).

**Wrap up:**

Here a simplified class model that shows the general structure.  I leave however the client, the invoker, the director and the builder out of this figure, as it depends very much on the rest of your application:

[image]